# TFS license for user account, not person?

Tags: license, team-foundation-server

We have 10 software engineers who all have valid TFS user licenses (either MSDN Pro/Ent). We also have an extra domain user account that everyone shares to access a remote PC in our office. This PC remains logged on as with this user account (and locked until we remote onto it) running a few scripts/applications that check code in and out of version control on our TFS. All humans already have a license. Does this extra user account also need a TFS CAL?

Comment: I would address your volume licensing agreement. Or speak to your microsoft rep.

Comment: Most MSDN paper license cannot be transfered so this always logged in user couldn't be used by multiple different humans since you can reassign paper licenses, I mention paper licenses, because that's likely what you would have to use on this always logged in user, but contact Microsoft since while their license terms are clear they are lots of requirements

Comment: Read the Visual studio licensing white paper, make sure it's the one for the version of TFS you are using. Worst case you can buy a Machine license, but I believe that you may be covered by the clause that allows a free license for build servers.

Comment: These remote PCs using the shared user account do use Visual Studio to build our software, but it's not part of the TFS build services model.  As far as TFS is concerned it's just remote clients checking in and out code.  The team considers it a build server though. It uses the 3rd party tool Visual Build, which grabs the latest code from TFS and then locally uses Visual Studio to build our software.

Comment: From the white paper, the following sounds like a possibility:    **Accessing Visual Studio Team Foundation Server through a pooled connection from another integrated
application or service.** This removes licensing friction from integrating TFS with LOB applications like customer
ticketing solutions and other ALM solutions.